# Getting value after added input box

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

i use a javascript to add a input box in my table as below:

```
var inputtopik = "topik" + 1;
$("#titleinput tbody").append("<tr><td> Topik " + topikno +
                              " : </td><td><input type='text' id='" +
                              inputtopik +"' style='WIDTH:498px;' ></td></tr>");
```

and then try to get the value  by this

```
var topik = document.getElementById('inputtopik').value;
```

but got an error state

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

i wonder why? maybe it cannot find the input box that ive just add? how to fix?
help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the value of inputtopik is "topik1". So you should do

```
var topik = document.getElementByID(inputtopik).value;
```

without the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery... one other way to get the value of input text is this:

```
var topik = $('#topik1').val();
```